# Plotly - how to plot Cylinder?

Tags: python, plotly

I have a function plotting the cylinder, using matplotlib.
[image]

I am wondering how to do the same using plotly?

below is my matplotlib function of plotting cylinder:

```
        #function to plot the cylinder
        def _plotCylinder(self, ax, x, y, z, dx, dy, dz, color='red',mode=2):
            """ Auxiliary function to plot a Cylinder  """
            # plot the two circles above and below the cylinder
            p = Circle((x+dx/2,y+dy/2),radius=dx/2,color=color,ec='black')
            p2 = Circle((x+dx/2,y+dy/2),radius=dx/2,color=color,ec='black')
            ax.add_patch(p)
            ax.add_patch(p2)
            art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(p, z=z, zdir="z")
            art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(p2, z=z+dz, zdir="z")
            # plot a circle in the middle of the cylinder
            center_z = np.linspace(0, dz, 15)
            theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 15)
            theta_grid, z_grid=np.meshgrid(theta, center_z)
            x_grid = dx / 2 * np.cos(theta_grid) + x + dx / 2
            y_grid = dy / 2 * np.sin(theta_grid) + y + dy / 2
            z_grid = z_grid + z
            ax.plot_surface(x_grid, y_grid, z_grid,shade=False,fc=color,ec='black',alpha=1,color=color)
    x,y,z = item.position
    [w,h,d] = item.getDimension()
    # plot item of cylinder
    self._plotCylinder(axGlob, float(x), float(y), float(z), float(w),float(h),float(d),color=color,mode=2)
```

**UPDATE - current code for drawing cube type of items**

```
### PLOTLY ###
# https://plotly.com/python/3d-mesh/#mesh-cube
def vertices(xmin=0, ymin=0, zmin=0, xmax=1, ymax=1, zmax=1):
    return {
        "x": [xmin, xmin, xmax, xmax, xmin, xmin, xmax, xmax],
        "y": [ymin, ymax, ymax, ymin, ymin, ymax, ymax, ymin],
        "z": [zmin, zmin, zmin, zmin, zmax, zmax, zmax, zmax],
        "i": [7, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 6, 1, 4, 0, 3, 6],
        "j": [3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 5, 2, 0, 1, 6, 3],
        "k": [0, 7, 2, 3, 6, 7, 1, 6, 5, 5, 7, 2],
    }



def parallelipipedic_frame(xm, xM, ym, yM, zm, zM):
    # defines the coords of each segment followed by None, if the line is
    # discontinuous
    x = [xm, xM, xM, xm, xm, None, xm, xM, xM, xm, xm, None, xm, xm, None, xM, xM,
         None, xM, xM, None, xm, xm]
    y = [ym, ym, yM, yM, ym, None, ym, ym, yM, yM, ym, None, ym, ym, None, ym, ym,
         None, yM, yM, None, yM, yM]
    z = [zm, zm, zm, zm, zm, None, zM, zM, zM, zM, zM, None, zm, zM, None, zm, zM,
         None, zm, zM, None, zm, zM]
    return x, y, z

# take a packer item and build parameters to a plotly mesh3d cube
def packer_to_plotly(item):
    colors = ["crimson", "limegreen", "green", "red", "cyan", "magenta", "yellow"]

    ret = vertices(
        *item.position, *[sum(x) for x in zip(item.position, item.getDimension())]
    )
    ret["name"] = item.name
    ret["color"] = colors[ord(item.name.split("_")[0][-1]) - ord("A")]
    return ret

# create a multi-plot figure for each bin
# fig = make_subplots(rows=len(packer.bins), cols=1, specs=[[{"type":"mesh3d"}], [{"type":"mesh3d"}]])
fig = go.Figure()

# add a trace for each packer item
for row, pbin in enumerate(packer.bins):
    for item in pbin.items:
        fig.add_trace(go.Mesh3d(packer_to_plotly(item)))

    # sorting out layout, prmarily aspect ratio
    fig.update_layout(
        margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
        autosize=False,
        scene=dict(
            camera=dict(
                # eye=dict(x=0.1, y=0.1, z=1.5)
            ),
            aspectratio=dict(x=1, y=.2, z=0.2),
            aspectmode="manual",
        ),
    )


    # push data into a data frame to enable more types of analysis
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            "bin_name": b.partno,
            "bin_index": i,
            **packer_to_plotly(item),
            **{d: v for v, d in zip(item.getDimension(), list("hwl"))},
            **{d + d: v for v, d in zip(item.position, list("xyz"))},
        }
        for i, b in enumerate(packer.bins)
        for item in b.items
    ]
)

# create a figure for each container (bin)
for pbin, d in df.groupby("bin_name"):
    fig = go.Figure()
    xx = []
    yy = []
    zz = []

    # create a trace for each box (bin)
    for _, r in d.iterrows():
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Mesh3d(r[["x", "y", "z", "i", "j", "k", "name", "color"]].to_dict())
        )
        xx += [r.xx, r.xx + r.h, r.xx + r.h, r.xx, r.xx, None] * 2 + [r.xx] * 5 + [None]
        yy += [r.yy, r.yy, r.yy + r.w, r.yy + r.w, r.yy, None] * 2 + [
            r.yy,
            r.yy + r.w,
            r.yy + r.w,
            r.yy,
            r.yy,
            None,
        ]
        zz += (
            [r.zz] * 5
            + [None]
            + [r.zz + r.l] * 5
            + [None]
            + [r.zz, r.zz, r.zz + r.l, r.zz + r.l, r.zz, None]
        )

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter3d(
            x=xx,
            y=yy,
            z=zz,
            mode="lines",
            line_color="black",
            line_width=2,
            hoverinfo="skip",
        )
    )

    x, y, z = parallelipipedic_frame(0, 1202.4, 0, 235, 0, 269.7)

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter3d(
            x=x,
            y=y,
            z=z,
            mode="lines",
            line_color="blue",
            line_width=2,
            hoverinfo="skip",
        )
    )

    ar = 4
    xr = max(d["x"].max()) - min(d["x"].min())
    fig.update_layout(
        showlegend=False,
        title={"text": pbin, "y": 0.9, "x": 0.5, "xanchor": "center", "yanchor": "top"},
        margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
        # autosize=False,
        scene=dict(
            camera=dict(eye=dict(x=2, y=2, z=2)),
            aspectratio={
                **{"x": ar},
                **{
                    c: ((max(d[c].max()) - min(d[c].min())) / xr) * ar
                    for c in list("yz")
                },
            },
            aspectmode="manual",
        ),
    )
fig.show()
```

Comment: There are [examples](https://community.plotly.com/t/basic-3d-cylinders/27990) in the plotly community, so let's see what you have to say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the chance to spend some time over the problem of creating a cylinder mesh, hence working on the triangulation.

Here is the result. The main function is `cylinder_traces`: it returns the `go.Surface` trace, and optionally `go.Scatter3d` traces representing the wireframe mesh.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

def slice_triangles(z, n, i, j, k, l):
    """Create the triangles of a single slice"""
    return [[z, j, i], [i, j, l], [l, j, k], [k, n, l]]

def cylinder_mesh(r, xs, ys, zs, h, n_slices=40):
    """Create a cylindrical mesh"""
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n_slices + 1)
    x = xs + r * np.cos(theta)
    y = ys + r * np.sin(theta)
    z1 = zs + 0 * np.ones_like(x)
    z2 = (zs + h) * np.ones_like(x)
    
    # index of the final point in the mesh
    n = n_slices * 2 + 1
    
    # build triangulation
    triangles = []
    for s in range(1, n_slices + 1):
        j = (s + 1) if (s <= n_slices - 1) else 1
        k = j + n_slices if (s <= n_slices - 1) else n_slices + 1
        l = s + n_slices
        triangles += slice_triangles(0, n, s, j, k, l)
    triangles = np.array(triangles)
    
    # coordinates of the vertices
    x_coords = np.hstack([xs, x[:-1], x[:-1], xs])
    y_coords = np.hstack([ys, y[:-1], y[:-1], ys])
    z_coords = np.hstack([zs, z1[:-1], z2[:-1], (zs + h)])
    vertices = np.stack([x_coords, y_coords, z_coords]).T
    
    return vertices, triangles, x, y, z1, z2

def cylinder_traces(r, xs, ys, zs, h, n_slices=40, show_mesh=True, n_sub=4, surface_kw={}, line_kw={}):
    """
    r : radius
    xs, ys, zs : start position of the cylinder
    h : height of the cylinder
    n_slices : number of slices in the circumferential direction
    show_mesh : wheter to display pseudo-wireframe
    n_sub : number of subdivision in along the height for the pseudo-wireframe
    surface_kw : customize the appearance of the surface
    line_kw : customize the appearance of the wireframe
    """
    vertices, triangles, x, y, z1, z2 = cylinder_mesh(r, xs, ys, zs, h, n_slices)
    surface = go.Mesh3d(
        x=vertices[:, 0], y=vertices[:, 1], z=vertices[:, 2],
        i=triangles[:, 0], j=triangles[:, 1], k=triangles[:, 2],
        **surface_kw)
    
    traces = [surface]
    if not show_mesh:
        return traces
    
    line_kw.setdefault("showlegend", False)
    # horizontal mesh lines
    zsubs = np.linspace(zs, zs + h, n_sub + 1)
    for zc in zsubs:
        traces.append(go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y, z=zc*np.ones_like(x), mode="lines", **line_kw))
    # vertical mesh lines
    for _x, _y in zip(x, y):
        traces.append(go.Scatter3d(x=[_x, _x], y=[_y, _y], z=[zs, zs + h], mode="lines", **line_kw))
    return traces

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_traces(
    cylinder_traces(2, 5, 3, 1, 4, 20, n_sub=4, line_kw={"line_color":"#202020", "line_width": 3})
)
fig
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**: The OP is probably concerned with the caps of the cylinder. So, we need to create:

- a surface for the cylinder wall, which is similar to what you already did with matplotlib.
- a surface for the bottom cap.
- a surface for the top cap.

Note: in the following picture I used different colors for the cylinder wall and the caps to better visualize them.

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def cylinder(x, y, z, r, dz):
    """Create a cylindrical mesh located at x, y, z, with radius r and height dz"""
    center_z = np.linspace(0, dz, 15)
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 15)
    theta_grid, z_grid = np.meshgrid(theta, center_z)
    x_grid = r * np.cos(theta_grid) + x
    y_grid = r * np.sin(theta_grid) + y
    z_grid = z_grid + z
    return x_grid, y_grid, z_grid

def circle(x, y, z, r):
    """Create a circular mesh located at x, y, z with radius r"""
    r_discr = np.linspace(0, r, 2)
    theta_discr = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 15)
    r_grid, theta_grid = np.meshgrid(r_discr, theta_discr)
    x_circle = r_grid * np.cos(theta_grid) + x
    y_circle = r_grid * np.sin(theta_grid) + y
    z_circle = np.zeros_like(x_circle) + z
    return x_circle, y_circle, z_circle

# cylinder mesh
x_cyl, y_cyl, z_cyl = cylinder(0, 0, 0, 2, 8)
# bottom cap
x_circle1, y_circle1, z_circle1 = circle(0, 0, 0, 2)
# top cap
x_circle2, y_circle2, z_circle2 = circle(0, 0, 8, 2)

colorscale = [[0, '#636EFA'],
             [1, '#636EFA']]

fig = go.Figure([
    go.Surface(x=x_cyl, y=y_cyl, z=z_cyl, colorscale=colorscale, showscale=False, opacity=0.5),
    go.Surface(x=x_circle1, y=y_circle1, z=z_circle1, showscale=False, opacity=0.5),
    go.Surface(x=x_circle2, y=y_circle2, z=z_circle2, showscale=False, opacity=0.5),
])
fig
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot.  1) how to make it more round (full circle)? 2) how to draw the cylindar item via fig.add_trace method (in my update above please see my current plotly code of drawing cube, where I used add_trace to draw individual items in a box/container)

Comment: Regarding 1), increase the number of discretization points from `15` to something bigger. Regarding 2) I cannot help you. First, your example is not reproducible. What is packer? How do I install it? Don't know. Second, you cannot change the scope of the question once an answer has been provided. I spent time to build and test this answer. You changing the scope of the question after I posted this answer is not fair towards me or any other people that might have spent time on this question. My answer satisfies your original question, and should be marked as the solution to that question.

Comment: thanks, I would try to figure out the solution to integrate with my model. If not, would u mind I open a new question for add_trace method solution?

Comment: Feel free to open a new question, but make sure to be specific!

Comment: I have tried to adapt your code to my own model but still not sucessful due to my limited knowledge on the plotly function. So I am seeking further help and opened a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72205704/plotly-drawing-both-cube-and-cylinder-items  Could you please take a look to help me. thank you very much