# Plotly - drawing both cube and cylinder items

Tags: python, plotly

I am dealing with an issue of drawing cylinder item as a result of a 3D bin packing model. There is a simple example drawing cylinder item which can be referenced at: [Plotly - how to plot Cylinder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72182976/plotly-how-to-plot-cylinder/72183849?noredirect=1#comment127545123_72183849)

However, here I have the difficaulties for make it work in my own model drawing function, possibly due to the existing way of drawing the cube items and add_trace method. How to enable drawing both the cube and cylinder items given the current code structure?

```
from py3dbp import Packer, Bin, Item, Painter
import time
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly
import pandas as pd
start = time.time()
import numpy as np


#-----------this part is about calculating the 3D bin packing problem to get x,y,z for each items of a bin/container--------------
###library reference: https://github.com/jerry800416/3D-bin-packing 

# init packing function
packer = Packer()
#  init bin
# box = Bin('40HC-1', (1203, 235, 259), 18000.0,0,0)
box = Bin('40HC-1', (1202.4, 235, 269.7), 18000.0,0,0)
packer.addBin(box)


# add item
for num in range(10):
    packer.addItem(Item(f"BoxA_{num}", f"BoxA_{num}",'cube',(120, 120, 120), 8.20,1,100,True,'red'))
for num in range(55):
    packer.addItem(Item(f"BoxB_{num}", f"BoxB_{num}",'cube',(65, 38, 90), 14,1,100,True,'blue'))
for num in range(50):
    packer.addItem(Item(f"BoxC_{num}", f"BoxC_{num}",'cube',(143, 52, 47), 10,1,100,True,'gray'))


# calculate packing 
packer.pack(bigger_first=True,distribute_items=False,fix_point=True,number_of_decimals=0)

# print result
b = packer.bins[0]
volume = b.width * b.height * b.depth
print(":::::::::::", b.string())

print("FITTED ITEMS:")
volume_t = 0
volume_f = 0
unfitted_name = ''
for item in b.items:
    print("partno : ",item.partno)
    print("color : ",item.color)
    print("position : ",item.position)
    print("rotation type : ",item.rotation_type)
    print("W*H*D : ",str(item.width) +'*'+ str(item.height) +'*'+ str(item.depth))
    print("volume : ",float(item.width) * float(item.height) * float(item.depth))
    print("weight : ",float(item.weight))
    volume_t += float(item.width) * float(item.height) * float(item.depth)
    print("***************************************************")
print("***************************************************")
print("UNFITTED ITEMS:")
for item in b.unfitted_items:
    print("partno : ",item.partno)
    print("color : ",item.color)
    print("W*H*D : ",str(item.width) +'*'+ str(item.height) +'*'+ str(item.depth))
    print("volume : ",float(item.width) * float(item.height) * float(item.depth))
    print("weight : ",float(item.weight))
    volume_f += float(item.width) * float(item.height) * float(item.depth)
    unfitted_name += '{},'.format(item.partno)
    print("***************************************************")
print("***************************************************")
print('space utilization : {}%'.format(round(volume_t / float(volume) * 100 ,2)))
print('residual volumn : ', float(volume) - volume_t )
print('unpack item : ',unfitted_name)
print('unpack item volumn : ',volume_f)
print("gravity distribution : ",b.gravity)
stop = time.time()
print('used time : ',stop - start)

# draw results
# painter = Painter(b)
# painter.plotBoxAndItems()

#----------------------------------end---------------------------------------------


############################### PLOTLY ############################################
# https://plotly.com/python/3d-mesh/#mesh-cube
def vertices(xmin=0, ymin=0, zmin=0, xmax=1, ymax=1, zmax=1):
    return {
        "x": [xmin, xmin, xmax, xmax, xmin, xmin, xmax, xmax],
        "y": [ymin, ymax, ymax, ymin, ymin, ymax, ymax, ymin],
        "z": [zmin, zmin, zmin, zmin, zmax, zmax, zmax, zmax],
        "i": [7, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 6, 1, 4, 0, 3, 6],
        "j": [3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 5, 2, 0, 1, 6, 3],
        "k": [0, 7, 2, 3, 6, 7, 1, 6, 5, 5, 7, 2],
    }


def parallelipipedic_frame(xm, xM, ym, yM, zm, zM):
    # defines the coords of each segment followed by None, if the line is
    # discontinuous
    x = [xm, xM, xM, xm, xm, None, xm, xM, xM, xm, xm, None, xm, xm, None, xM, xM,
         None, xM, xM, None, xm, xm]
    y = [ym, ym, yM, yM, ym, None, ym, ym, yM, yM, ym, None, ym, ym, None, ym, ym,
         None, yM, yM, None, yM, yM]
    z = [zm, zm, zm, zm, zm, None, zM, zM, zM, zM, zM, None, zm, zM, None, zm, zM,
         None, zm, zM, None, zm, zM]
    return x, y, z


def cylinder(x, y, z, r, dz):
    """Create a cylindrical mesh located at x, y, z, with radius r and height dz"""
    center_z = np.linspace(0, dz, 35)
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 35)
    theta_grid, z_grid = np.meshgrid(theta, center_z)
    x_grid = r * np.cos(theta_grid) + x
    y_grid = r * np.sin(theta_grid) + y
    z_grid = z_grid + z
    return x_grid, y_grid, z_grid


def circle(x, y, z, r):
    """Create a circular mesh located at x, y, z with radius r"""
    r_discr = np.linspace(0, r, 2)
    theta_discr = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 35)
    r_grid, theta_grid = np.meshgrid(r_discr, theta_discr)
    x_circle = r_grid * np.cos(theta_grid) + x
    y_circle = r_grid * np.sin(theta_grid) + y
    z_circle = np.zeros_like(x_circle) + z
    return x_circle, y_circle, z_circle




# take a packer item and build parameters to a plotly mesh3d cube
def packer_to_plotly(item):
    colors = ["crimson", "limegreen", "green", "red", "cyan", "magenta", "yellow"]

    ret = vertices(
        *item.position, *[sum(x) for x in zip(item.position, item.getDimension())]
    )
    ret["name"] = item.name
    ret["color"] = colors[ord(item.name.split("_")[0][-1]) - ord("A")]
    return ret

# create a figure for each bin
fig = go.Figure()

# add a trace for each packer item
for row, pbin in enumerate(packer.bins):
    for item in pbin.items:
        fig.add_trace(go.Mesh3d(packer_to_plotly(item)))

    # some first attempts at sorting out layout, prmarily aspect ratio
    fig.update_layout(
        margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
        autosize=False,
        scene=dict(
            camera=dict(
                # eye=dict(x=0.1, y=0.1, z=1.5)
            ),
            aspectratio=dict(x=1, y=.2, z=0.2),
            aspectmode="manual",
        ),
    )

    # plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='C:/Users/Jie/Desktop/3D_BinPack_' + str(row) + '.html', auto_open=False,
    #                       config={'displaylogo': False})


    # push data into a data frame to enable more types of analysis
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            "bin_name": b.partno,
            "bin_index": i,
            **packer_to_plotly(item),
            **{d: v for v, d in zip(item.getDimension(), list("hwl"))},
            **{d + d: v for v, d in zip(item.position, list("xyz"))},
        }
        for i, b in enumerate(packer.bins)
        for item in b.items
    ]
)

# create a figure for each container (bin)
for pbin, d in df.groupby("bin_name"):
    fig = go.Figure()
    xx = []
    yy = []
    zz = []

    # create a trace for each box (bin)
    for _, r in d.iterrows():
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Mesh3d(r[["x", "y", "z", "i", "j", "k", "name", "color"]].to_dict())
        )
        xx += [r.xx, r.xx + r.h, r.xx + r.h, r.xx, r.xx, None] * 2 + [r.xx] * 5 + [None]
        yy += [r.yy, r.yy, r.yy + r.w, r.yy + r.w, r.yy, None] * 2 + [
            r.yy,
            r.yy + r.w,
            r.yy + r.w,
            r.yy,
            r.yy,
            None,
        ]
        zz += (
            [r.zz] * 5
            + [None]
            + [r.zz + r.l] * 5
            + [None]
            + [r.zz, r.zz, r.zz + r.l, r.zz + r.l, r.zz, None]
        )

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter3d(
            x=xx,
            y=yy,
            z=zz,
            mode="lines",
            line_color="black",
            line_width=2,
            hoverinfo="skip",
        )
    )

    x, y, z = parallelipipedic_frame(0, 1202.4, 0, 235, 0, 269.7)
    # fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, mode="lines", line_width=4))

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter3d(
            x=x,
            y=y,
            z=z,
            mode="lines",
            line_color="blue",
            line_width=2,
            hoverinfo="skip",
        )
    )


    # -----------------newly added code to test plotting cylinder: NOT WORKING!-------------------
    # cylinder mesh
    x_cyl, y_cyl, z_cyl = cylinder(0, 0, 0, 50, 80)
    # bottom cap
    x_circle1, y_circle1, z_circle1 = circle(0, 0, 0, 50)
    # top cap
    x_circle2, y_circle2, z_circle2 = circle(0, 0, 80, 50)

    colorscale = [[0, '#636EFA'],
                  [1, '#636EFA']]


    fig.add_trace(
        go.Surface(x=x_cyl, y=y_cyl, z=z_cyl, colorscale=colorscale, showscale=False, opacity=0.5),
        go.Surface(x=x_circle1, y=y_circle1, z=z_circle1, showscale=False, opacity=0.5),
        go.Surface(x=x_circle2, y=y_circle2, z=z_circle2, showscale=False, opacity=0.5),
    )

    # -----------------end for newly added code to test plotting cylinder-------------------




    ar = 4
    xr = max(d["x"].max()) - min(d["x"].min())
    fig.update_layout(
        showlegend=False,
        title={"text": pbin, "y": 0.9, "x": 0.5, "xanchor": "center", "yanchor": "top"},
        margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
        # autosize=False,
        scene=dict(
            camera=dict(eye=dict(x=2, y=2, z=2)),
            aspectratio={
                **{"x": ar},
                **{
                    c: ((max(d[c].max()) - min(d[c].min())) / xr) * ar
                    for c in list("yz")
                },
            },
            aspectmode="manual",
        ),
    )


    fig.show(config= {'displaylogo': False})
```

**UPDATE for drawing cylinder from items:**

```
from py3dbp import Packer, Bin, Item, Painter
import time
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly
import pandas as pd

start = time.time()
import numpy as np

# -----------this part is about calculating the 3D bin packing problem to get x,y,z for each items of a bin/container--------------
###library reference: https://github.com/jerry800416/3D-bin-packing

# init packing function
packer = Packer()
#  init bin
# box = Bin('40HC-1', (1203, 235, 259), 18000.0,0,0)
box = Bin('40HC-1', (1202.4, 235, 269.7), 18000.0, 0, 0)
packer.addBin(box)


# add item
# for num in range(10):
#   packer.addItem(Item(f"BoxA_{num}", f"BoxA_{num}", 'cube', (120, 120, 120), 8.20, 1, 100, True, 'red'))
# for num in range(55):
#   packer.addItem(Item(f"BoxB_{num}", f"BoxB_{num}", 'cube', (65, 38, 90), 14, 1, 100, True, 'blue'))
# for num in range(50):
#   packer.addItem(Item(f"BoxC_{num}", f"BoxC_{num}", 'cube', (143, 52, 47), 10, 1, 100, True, 'gray'))


# add item
for num in range(3):
    packer.addItem(Item(f"BoxA_{num}", f"BoxA_{num}", 'cylinder', (120, 120, 120), 8.20, 1, 100, True, 'red'))
for num in range(3):
    packer.addItem(Item(f"BoxB_{num}", f"BoxB_{num}", 'cube', (65, 38, 90), 14, 1, 100, True, 'blue'))
for num in range(2):
    packer.addItem(Item(f"BoxC_{num}", f"BoxC_{num}", 'cube', (143, 52, 47), 10, 1, 100, True, 'gray'))



# calculate packing
packer.pack(bigger_first=True, distribute_items=False, fix_point=True, number_of_decimals=0)

# print result
b = packer.bins[0]
volume = b.width * b.height * b.depth
print(":::::::::::", b.string())

print("FITTED ITEMS:")
volume_t = 0
volume_f = 0
unfitted_name = ''
for item in b.items:
    print("partno : ", item.partno)
    print("color : ", item.color)
    print("position : ", item.position)
    print("type of : ", item.typeof)
    print("rotation type : ", item.rotation_type)
    print("W*H*D : ", str(item.width) + '*' + str(item.height) + '*' + str(item.depth))
    print("volume : ", float(item.width) * float(item.height) * float(item.depth))
    print("weight : ", float(item.weight))
    volume_t += float(item.width) * float(item.height) * float(item.depth)
    print("***************************************************")
print("***************************************************")
print("UNFITTED ITEMS:")
for item in b.unfitted_items:
    print("partno : ", item.partno)
    print("color : ", item.color)
    print("W*H*D : ", str(item.width) + '*' + str(item.height) + '*' + str(item.depth))
    print("volume : ", float(item.width) * float(item.height) * float(item.depth))
    print("weight : ", float(item.weight))
    volume_f += float(item.width) * float(item.height) * float(item.depth)
    unfitted_name += '{},'.format(item.partno)
    print("***************************************************")
print("***************************************************")
print('space utilization : {}%'.format(round(volume_t / float(volume) * 100, 2)))
print('residual volumn : ', float(volume) - volume_t)
print('unpack item : ', unfitted_name)
print('unpack item volumn : ', volume_f)
print("gravity distribution : ", b.gravity)
stop = time.time()
print('used time : ', stop - start)


# draw results
# painter = Painter(b)
# painter.plotBoxAndItems()

# ----------------------------------end---------------------------------------------


############################### PLOTLY ############################################
# https://plotly.com/python/3d-mesh/#mesh-cube
def vertices(xmin=0, ymin=0, zmin=0, xmax=1, ymax=1, zmax=1):
    return {
        "x": [xmin, xmin, xmax, xmax, xmin, xmin, xmax, xmax],
        "y": [ymin, ymax, ymax, ymin, ymin, ymax, ymax, ymin],
        "z": [zmin, zmin, zmin, zmin, zmax, zmax, zmax, zmax],
        "i": [7, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 6, 1, 4, 0, 3, 6],
        "j": [3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 5, 2, 0, 1, 6, 3],
        "k": [0, 7, 2, 3, 6, 7, 1, 6, 5, 5, 7, 2],
    }


def parallelipipedic_frame(xm, xM, ym, yM, zm, zM):
    # defines the coords of each segment followed by None, if the line is
    # discontinuous
    x = [xm, xM, xM, xm, xm, None, xm, xM, xM, xm, xm, None, xm, xm, None, xM, xM,
         None, xM, xM, None, xm, xm]
    y = [ym, ym, yM, yM, ym, None, ym, ym, yM, yM, ym, None, ym, ym, None, ym, ym,
         None, yM, yM, None, yM, yM]
    z = [zm, zm, zm, zm, zm, None, zM, zM, zM, zM, zM, None, zm, zM, None, zm, zM,
         None, zm, zM, None, zm, zM]
    return x, y, z


def slice_triangles(z, n, i, j, k, l):
    """Create the triangles of a single slice"""
    return [[z, j, i], [i, j, l], [l, j, k], [k, n, l]]


def cylinder_mesh(r, xs, ys, zs, h, n_slices=40):
    """Create a cylindrical mesh"""
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n_slices + 1)
    x = xs + r * np.cos(theta)
    y = ys + r * np.sin(theta)
    z1 = zs + 0 * np.ones_like(x)
    z2 = (zs + h) * np.ones_like(x)

    # index of the final point in the mesh
    n = n_slices * 2 + 1

    # build triangulation
    triangles = []
    for s in range(1, n_slices + 1):
        j = (s + 1) if (s <= n_slices - 1) else 1
        k = j + n_slices if (s <= n_slices - 1) else n_slices + 1
        l = s + n_slices
        triangles += slice_triangles(0, n, s, j, k, l)
    triangles = np.array(triangles)

    # coordinates of the vertices
    x_coords = np.hstack([xs, x[:-1], x[:-1], xs])
    y_coords = np.hstack([ys, y[:-1], y[:-1], ys])
    z_coords = np.hstack([zs, z1[:-1], z2[:-1], (zs + h)])
    vertices = np.stack([x_coords, y_coords, z_coords]).T

    return vertices, triangles, x, y, z1, z2


def cylinder_traces(r, xs, ys, zs, h, n_slices=40, show_mesh=True, n_sub=4, surface_kw={}, line_kw={}):
    """
    r : radius
    xs, ys, zs : start position of the cylinder
    h : height of the cylinder
    n_slices : number of slices in the circumferential direction
    show_mesh : wheter to display pseudo-wireframe
    n_sub : number of subdivision in along the height for the pseudo-wireframe
    surface_kw : customize the appearance of the surface
    line_kw : customize the appearance of the wireframe
    """
    vertices, triangles, x, y, z1, z2 = cylinder_mesh(r, xs, ys, zs, h, n_slices)
    surface = go.Mesh3d(
        x=vertices[:, 0], y=vertices[:, 1], z=vertices[:, 2],
        i=triangles[:, 0], j=triangles[:, 1], k=triangles[:, 2],
        **surface_kw)

    traces = [surface]
    if not show_mesh:
        return traces

    line_kw.setdefault("showlegend", False)
    # horizontal mesh lines
    zsubs = np.linspace(zs, zs + h, n_sub + 1)
    for zc in zsubs:
        traces.append(go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y, z=zc * np.ones_like(x), mode="lines", **line_kw))
    # vertical mesh lines
    for _x, _y in zip(x, y):
        traces.append(go.Scatter3d(x=[_x, _x], y=[_y, _y], z=[zs, zs + h], mode="lines", **line_kw))
    return traces


# take a packer item and build parameters to a plotly mesh3d cube
def packer_to_plotly(item):
    colors = ["crimson", "limegreen", "green", "red", "cyan", "magenta", "yellow"]

    ret = vertices(
        *item.position, *[sum(x) for x in zip(item.position, item.getDimension())]
    )
    ret["name"] = item.name
    # print("item.typeof!!!!!! ", item.typeof)
    # ret["typeof"] = item.typeof
    ret["color"] = colors[ord(item.name.split("_")[0][-1]) - ord("A")]
    # ret["typeof"] = item.typeof
    return ret


# create a figure for each bin
fig = go.Figure()

# add a trace for each packer item
for row, pbin in enumerate(packer.bins):
    for item in pbin.items:
        fig.add_trace(go.Mesh3d(packer_to_plotly(item)))

    # some first attempts at sorting out layout, prmarily aspect ratio
    fig.update_layout(
        margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
        autosize=False,
        scene=dict(
            camera=dict(
                # eye=dict(x=0.1, y=0.1, z=1.5)
            ),
            aspectratio=dict(x=1, y=.2, z=0.2),
            aspectmode="manual",
        ),
    )

# push data into a data frame to enable more types of analysis
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            "bin_name": b.partno,
            "bin_index": i,
            **packer_to_plotly(item),
            "item_typeof": item.typeof,
            **{d: v for v, d in zip(item.getDimension(), list("hwl"))},
            **{d + d: v for v, d in zip(item.position, list("xyz"))},
        }
        for i, b in enumerate(packer.bins)
        for item in b.items
    ]
)
print("dataframe: \n", df['item_typeof'])

# create a figure for each container (bin)
for pbin, d in df.groupby("bin_name"):
    fig = go.Figure()
    xx = []
    yy = []
    zz = []

    # create a trace for each box (bin)
    for _, r in d.iterrows():
        print("_, ", _,)
        print("r ", r)
        if r["item_typeof"] == 'cube':
            fig.add_trace(
                go.Mesh3d(r[["x", "y", "z", "i", "j", "k", "name", "color"]].to_dict())
            )
            xx += [r.xx, r.xx + r.h, r.xx + r.h, r.xx, r.xx, None] * 2 + [r.xx] * 5 + [None]
            yy += [r.yy, r.yy, r.yy + r.w, r.yy + r.w, r.yy, None] * 2 + [
                r.yy,
                r.yy + r.w,
                r.yy + r.w,
                r.yy,
                r.yy,
                None,
            ]
            zz += (
                    [r.zz] * 5
                    + [None]
                    + [r.zz + r.l] * 5
                    + [None]
                    + [r.zz, r.zz, r.zz + r.l, r.zz + r.l, r.zz, None]
            )

            fig.add_trace(
                go.Scatter3d(
                    x=xx,
                    y=yy,
                    z=zz,
                    mode="lines",
                    line_color="black",
                    line_width=2,
                    hoverinfo="skip",
                )
            )
        else:
            radius = float(r["w"])/2
            height = float(r["l"])
            x_list = r["x"]
            y_list = r["y"]
            z_list = r["z"]
            x_min = float(min(x_list))
            x_max = float(max(x_list))
            y_min = float(min(y_list))
            y_max = float(max(y_list))
            x_cor = (x_max - x_min)/2
            y_cor = (y_max - y_min)/2
            z_cor = float(min(z_list))
            print("xyz! ", x_cor,y_cor,z_cor)
            fig.add_traces(
                cylinder_traces(radius, x_cor, y_cor, z_cor, height, n_sub=1, line_kw={"line_color": "#202020", "line_width": 3})
            )


    x, y, z = parallelipipedic_frame(0, 1202.4, 0, 235, 0, 269.7)

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter3d(
            x=x,
            y=y,
            z=z,
            mode="lines",
            line_color="blue",
            line_width=2,
            hoverinfo="skip",
        )
    )

    # -----------------newly added code to test plotting cylinder
    # fig.add_traces(
    #   cylinder_traces(50, 0, 0, 0, 80, n_sub=1, line_kw={"line_color": "#202020", "line_width": 3})
    # )

    # -----------------end for newly added code to test plotting cylinder-------------------

    ar = 4
    xr = max(d["x"].max()) - min(d["x"].min())
    # fig.update_layout(
    #   showlegend=False,
    #   title={"text": pbin, "y": 0.9, "x": 0.5, "xanchor": "center", "yanchor": "top"},
    #   margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
    #   # autosize=False,
    #   scene=dict(
    #       camera=dict(eye=dict(x=2, y=2, z=2)),
    #       aspectmode="data",
    #   ),
    # )
    fig.update_layout(
        showlegend=False,
        title={"text": pbin, "y": 0.9, "x": 0.5, "xanchor": "center", "yanchor": "top"},
        margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
        # autosize=False,
        scene=dict(
            camera=dict(eye=dict(x=2, y=2, z=2)),
            aspectratio={
                **{"x": ar},
                **{
                    c: ((max(d[c].max()) - min(d[c].min())) / xr) * ar
                    for c in list("yz")
                },
            },
            aspectmode="manual",
        ),
    )


    fig.show(config={'displaylogo': False})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: let's use a different method to generate the cylinder.

```
from py3dbp import Packer, Bin, Item, Painter
import time
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly
import pandas as pd
start = time.time()
import numpy as np


#-----------this part is about calculating the 3D bin packing problem to get x,y,z for each items of a bin/container--------------
###library reference: https://github.com/jerry800416/3D-bin-packing 

# init packing function
packer = Packer()
#  init bin
# box = Bin('40HC-1', (1203, 235, 259), 18000.0,0,0)
box = Bin('40HC-1', (1202.4, 235, 269.7), 18000.0,0,0)
packer.addBin(box)


# add item
for num in range(10):
    packer.addItem(Item(f"BoxA_{num}", f"BoxA_{num}",'cube',(120, 120, 120), 8.20,1,100,True,'red'))
for num in range(55):
    packer.addItem(Item(f"BoxB_{num}", f"BoxB_{num}",'cube',(65, 38, 90), 14,1,100,True,'blue'))
for num in range(50):
    packer.addItem(Item(f"BoxC_{num}", f"BoxC_{num}",'cube',(143, 52, 47), 10,1,100,True,'gray'))


# calculate packing 
packer.pack(bigger_first=True,distribute_items=False,fix_point=True,number_of_decimals=0)

# print result
b = packer.bins[0]
volume = b.width * b.height * b.depth
print(":::::::::::", b.string())

print("FITTED ITEMS:")
volume_t = 0
volume_f = 0
unfitted_name = ''
for item in b.items:
    print("partno : ",item.partno)
    print("color : ",item.color)
    print("position : ",item.position)
    print("rotation type : ",item.rotation_type)
    print("W*H*D : ",str(item.width) +'*'+ str(item.height) +'*'+ str(item.depth))
    print("volume : ",float(item.width) * float(item.height) * float(item.depth))
    print("weight : ",float(item.weight))
    volume_t += float(item.width) * float(item.height) * float(item.depth)
    print("***************************************************")
print("***************************************************")
print("UNFITTED ITEMS:")
for item in b.unfitted_items:
    print("partno : ",item.partno)
    print("color : ",item.color)
    print("W*H*D : ",str(item.width) +'*'+ str(item.height) +'*'+ str(item.depth))
    print("volume : ",float(item.width) * float(item.height) * float(item.depth))
    print("weight : ",float(item.weight))
    volume_f += float(item.width) * float(item.height) * float(item.depth)
    unfitted_name += '{},'.format(item.partno)
    print("***************************************************")
print("***************************************************")
print('space utilization : {}%'.format(round(volume_t / float(volume) * 100 ,2)))
print('residual volumn : ', float(volume) - volume_t )
print('unpack item : ',unfitted_name)
print('unpack item volumn : ',volume_f)
print("gravity distribution : ",b.gravity)
stop = time.time()
print('used time : ',stop - start)

# draw results
# painter = Painter(b)
# painter.plotBoxAndItems()

#----------------------------------end---------------------------------------------


############################### PLOTLY ############################################
# https://plotly.com/python/3d-mesh/#mesh-cube
def vertices(xmin=0, ymin=0, zmin=0, xmax=1, ymax=1, zmax=1):
    return {
        "x": [xmin, xmin, xmax, xmax, xmin, xmin, xmax, xmax],
        "y": [ymin, ymax, ymax, ymin, ymin, ymax, ymax, ymin],
        "z": [zmin, zmin, zmin, zmin, zmax, zmax, zmax, zmax],
        "i": [7, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 6, 1, 4, 0, 3, 6],
        "j": [3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 5, 2, 0, 1, 6, 3],
        "k": [0, 7, 2, 3, 6, 7, 1, 6, 5, 5, 7, 2],
    }


def parallelipipedic_frame(xm, xM, ym, yM, zm, zM):
    # defines the coords of each segment followed by None, if the line is
    # discontinuous
    x = [xm, xM, xM, xm, xm, None, xm, xM, xM, xm, xm, None, xm, xm, None, xM, xM,
         None, xM, xM, None, xm, xm]
    y = [ym, ym, yM, yM, ym, None, ym, ym, yM, yM, ym, None, ym, ym, None, ym, ym,
         None, yM, yM, None, yM, yM]
    z = [zm, zm, zm, zm, zm, None, zM, zM, zM, zM, zM, None, zm, zM, None, zm, zM,
         None, zm, zM, None, zm, zM]
    return x, y, z


def slice_triangles(z, n, i, j, k, l):
    """Create the triangles of a single slice"""
    return [[z, j, i], [i, j, l], [l, j, k], [k, n, l]]

def cylinder_mesh(r, xs, ys, zs, h, n_slices=40):
    """Create a cylindrical mesh"""
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n_slices + 1)
    x = xs + r * np.cos(theta)
    y = ys + r * np.sin(theta)
    z1 = zs + 0 * np.ones_like(x)
    z2 = (zs + h) * np.ones_like(x)
    
    # index of the final point in the mesh
    n = n_slices * 2 + 1
    
    # build triangulation
    triangles = []
    for s in range(1, n_slices + 1):
        j = (s + 1) if (s <= n_slices - 1) else 1
        k = j + n_slices if (s <= n_slices - 1) else n_slices + 1
        l = s + n_slices
        triangles += slice_triangles(0, n, s, j, k, l)
    triangles = np.array(triangles)
    
    # coordinates of the vertices
    x_coords = np.hstack([xs, x[:-1], x[:-1], xs])
    y_coords = np.hstack([ys, y[:-1], y[:-1], ys])
    z_coords = np.hstack([zs, z1[:-1], z2[:-1], (zs + h)])
    vertices = np.stack([x_coords, y_coords, z_coords]).T
    
    return vertices, triangles, x, y, z1, z2

def cylinder_traces(r, xs, ys, zs, h, n_slices=40, show_mesh=True, n_sub=4, surface_kw={}, line_kw={}):
    """
    r : radius
    xs, ys, zs : start position of the cylinder
    h : height of the cylinder
    n_slices : number of slices in the circumferential direction
    show_mesh : wheter to display pseudo-wireframe
    n_sub : number of subdivision in along the height for the pseudo-wireframe
    surface_kw : customize the appearance of the surface
    line_kw : customize the appearance of the wireframe
    """
    vertices, triangles, x, y, z1, z2 = cylinder_mesh(r, xs, ys, zs, h, n_slices)
    surface = go.Mesh3d(
        x=vertices[:, 0], y=vertices[:, 1], z=vertices[:, 2],
        i=triangles[:, 0], j=triangles[:, 1], k=triangles[:, 2],
        **surface_kw)
    
    traces = [surface]
    if not show_mesh:
        return traces
    
    line_kw.setdefault("showlegend", False)
    # horizontal mesh lines
    zsubs = np.linspace(zs, zs + h, n_sub + 1)
    for zc in zsubs:
        traces.append(go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y, z=zc*np.ones_like(x), mode="lines", **line_kw))
    # vertical mesh lines
    for _x, _y in zip(x, y):
        traces.append(go.Scatter3d(x=[_x, _x], y=[_y, _y], z=[zs, zs + h], mode="lines", **line_kw))
    return traces




# take a packer item and build parameters to a plotly mesh3d cube
def packer_to_plotly(item):
    colors = ["crimson", "limegreen", "green", "red", "cyan", "magenta", "yellow"]

    ret = vertices(
        *item.position, *[sum(x) for x in zip(item.position, item.getDimension())]
    )
    ret["name"] = item.name
    ret["color"] = colors[ord(item.name.split("_")[0][-1]) - ord("A")]
    return ret

# create a figure for each bin
fig = go.Figure()

# add a trace for each packer item
for row, pbin in enumerate(packer.bins):
    for item in pbin.items:
        fig.add_trace(go.Mesh3d(packer_to_plotly(item)))

    # some first attempts at sorting out layout, prmarily aspect ratio
    fig.update_layout(
        margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
        autosize=False,
        scene=dict(
            camera=dict(
                # eye=dict(x=0.1, y=0.1, z=1.5)
            ),
            aspectratio=dict(x=1, y=.2, z=0.2),
            aspectmode="manual",
        ),
    )

    # plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='C:/Users/Jie/Desktop/3D_BinPack_' + str(row) + '.html', auto_open=False,
    #                       config={'displaylogo': False})


    # push data into a data frame to enable more types of analysis
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            "bin_name": b.partno,
            "bin_index": i,
            **packer_to_plotly(item),
            **{d: v for v, d in zip(item.getDimension(), list("hwl"))},
            **{d + d: v for v, d in zip(item.position, list("xyz"))},
        }
        for i, b in enumerate(packer.bins)
        for item in b.items
    ]
)

# create a figure for each container (bin)
for pbin, d in df.groupby("bin_name"):
    fig = go.Figure()
    xx = []
    yy = []
    zz = []

    # create a trace for each box (bin)
    for _, r in d.iterrows():
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Mesh3d(r[["x", "y", "z", "i", "j", "k", "name", "color"]].to_dict())
        )
        xx += [r.xx, r.xx + r.h, r.xx + r.h, r.xx, r.xx, None] * 2 + [r.xx] * 5 + [None]
        yy += [r.yy, r.yy, r.yy + r.w, r.yy + r.w, r.yy, None] * 2 + [
            r.yy,
            r.yy + r.w,
            r.yy + r.w,
            r.yy,
            r.yy,
            None,
        ]
        zz += (
            [r.zz] * 5
            + [None]
            + [r.zz + r.l] * 5
            + [None]
            + [r.zz, r.zz, r.zz + r.l, r.zz + r.l, r.zz, None]
        )

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter3d(
            x=xx,
            y=yy,
            z=zz,
            mode="lines",
            line_color="black",
            line_width=2,
            hoverinfo="skip",
        )
    )

    x, y, z = parallelipipedic_frame(0, 1202.4, 0, 235, 0, 269.7)
    # fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, mode="lines", line_width=4))

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter3d(
            x=x,
            y=y,
            z=z,
            mode="lines",
            line_color="blue",
            line_width=2,
            hoverinfo="skip",
        )
    )


    # -----------------newly added code to test plotting cylinder
    fig.add_traces(
         cylinder_traces(50, 0, 0, 0, 80, n_sub=1, line_kw={"line_color":"#202020", "line_width": 3})
    )
   

    # -----------------end for newly added code to test plotting cylinder-------------------




    ar = 4
    xr = max(d["x"].max()) - min(d["x"].min())
    fig.update_layout(
        showlegend=False,
        title={"text": pbin, "y": 0.9, "x": 0.5, "xanchor": "center", "yanchor": "top"},
        margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
        # autosize=False,
        scene=dict(
            camera=dict(eye=dict(x=2, y=2, z=2)),
            aspectmode="data",
        ),
    )


    fig.show(config= {'displaylogo': False})
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**: The problem is here:

```
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Surface(x=x_cyl, y=y_cyl, z=z_cyl, colorscale=colorscale, showscale=False, opacity=0.5),
        go.Surface(x=x_circle1, y=y_circle1, z=z_circle1, showscale=False, opacity=0.5),
        go.Surface(x=x_circle2, y=y_circle2, z=z_circle2, showscale=False, opacity=0.5),
    )
```

`add_trace`, as the name suggest, add a single trace. Instead, you are giving it three different traces. All you need to do is to use `add_traces`, like this:

```
fig.add_traces([
        go.Surface(x=x_cyl, y=y_cyl, z=z_cyl, colorscale=colorscale, showscale=False, opacity=0.5),
        go.Surface(x=x_circle1, y=y_circle1, z=z_circle1, showscale=False, opacity=0.5),
        go.Surface(x=x_circle2, y=y_circle2, z=z_circle2, showscale=False, opacity=0.5)
    ])
```

Comment: I have made the change, but still no cylinder item is plotted. only cube items... have you tested the codes?

Comment: I have tried plotting the exisiting cube items into cylinder, but not working. I think the x, y, z value calculated from function vertices() are different from your function cylinder() and circle(). This could be where the problem is. could you help to investigate further?

Comment: I've tried the code and the cylinder is visible. You just need to rotate the plot...

Comment: here you can see how each box is added with an attribute called "cube" or "cylinder" for num in range(10):
    packer.addItem(Item(f"BoxA_{num}", f"BoxA_{num}",'cube',(120, 120, 120), 8.20,1,100,True,'red'))    --- is there better way to systematically draw the graph based on this attribute?

Comment: I have never used `packer` so I have no idea!

Comment: Thanks a lot David. I have managed to modify the code to allow it drawing cylinder based on wether a item.typeof == 'cube' or 'cylinder'.  However, the problem here is that with your function the graph only draws and displays the first item that is identified as "cylinder item". where is the root cause?

Comment: sorry I made a simple mistake, the code should be: x_cor = x_min + (x_max - x_min)/2
   y_cor = y_min + (y_max - y_min)/2
   z_cor = float(min(z_list)) .  This will solve the problem. In addition, how do I assign same color to the same type of cube or cylinder? for cylinder, how to change the label from "trace id" to "box id"?

Comment: Create a new variable `colorscale = [[0, '#636EFA'], [1, '#636EFA']]`. Then replace this line of code: `cylinder_traces(radius, x_cor, y_cor, z_cor, height, n_sub=1, line_kw={"line_color": "#202020", "line_width": 3})` with this: `cylinder_traces(radius, x_cor, y_cor, z_cor, height, n_sub=1, line_kw={"line_color": "#202020", "line_width": 3}, surface_kw={"colorscale": colorscale})`

Comment: thanks I have tried but the color does not change. I think in original code the color is already assigned for items with same dimension (same type of item) in packer_to_plotly() and transformed in dataframe. I guess we just need to retrive this information during the loop for _, r in d.iterrows(): when r["item_typeof"] == 'cylinder': plot it with the predefined color?

Comment: for zc in zsubs:
  traces.append(go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y, z=zc * np.ones_like(x), mode="lines",name=box_id, **line_kw))
 # vertical mesh lines
 for _x, _y in zip(x, y):
  traces.append(go.Scatter3d(x=[_x, _x], y=[_y, _y], z=[zs, zs + h], mode="lines", name=box_id, **line_kw))  ----- the label of box_id can only be shown for horizontal lines of cylinder item. How to make vertical lines showing the same box_id when mouth pointing them?

Comment: I have absolutely NO idea what your are trying to do right now. Besides, the above answer perfectly solves the questions "drawing both cube and cylinders", so please mark it as the solution.

Comment: thank you David. I have marked it as a solution. I still have one last problem of displaying the cylinder item label. could you offer the help I spent whole day but not working. it could be very simple for you I guess. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72300228/plotly-issue-of-display-cylinder-label