# how to fix boxes and container dimensions?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

[Plotly - issue of display cylinder label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72300228/plotly-issue-of-display-cylinder-label)

how to fix boxes and container dimensions?

In the code in the link above , if you enter 1 or 5 boxes ((for num in range(5): packer.addItem()) here
You can try changing the "range" value to 1 and 5.) the box sizes and container size change, but the dimensions should always remain constant even if 1 box or 1000 boxes are entered.

For example, these boxes dimensions are 1x1x1 but it looks like 1x20x1 also container dimension are 10x10x10 but it is distorted too.

[image]

Comment: Does anyone needs any more information regarding not understanding or anything please let me know. I am willing to have the solution for this question.

Comment: I think you're going to have to include programming code on this forum for programming questions. I've taken the time to get the repo set up as an internal package and ran through the code you provided the link to. I've changed the numbers, but I'm not reproducing whatever it is you have discovered. It looks like you made many changes based on the container dimensions and the colors.  What's the main container code? What items does it contain?