# I drew 3D boxes for the container, but how do I draw a cylinder?

Tags: python, plotly

Below is the code that inserts the boxes into the container and inserts the boxes in 3D.
I want to enter the box dimensions, calculate the cylinder that will fit inside, and draw a cylinder instead of the box, but I couldn't. For example, if the color is "pink", draw a cylinder.

my main problem is: i drew 3d boxes for the container but how do i draw a cylinder?

It should also be the black line around the boxes.

First picture:  output i have

Second picture:  output i need

[image: output i have]

[image: output i need]

````
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.express as px
containers = [
    [1203, 235, 259],
   
    [1203, 235, 259],
]

packer = Packer()

for i, t in enumerate(containers):
    packer.add_bin(Bin("40HC-" + str(i + 1), *t, 1000.0))


pbins = {
    "BoxA": {"n": 5, "s": [40, 30, 70, 8.20]},
    "BoxB": {"n": 2, "s": [65, 38, 40, 14]},
    "BoxC": {"n": 11, "s": [43, 52, 47, 10]},
   "BoxD": {"n": 2, "s": [60, 45, 40, 14]},
   "BoxE": {"n": 1, "s": [65, 38, 40, 14]},
    "BoxF": {"n": 5, "s": [60, 40, 30, 14.5]},
}

for name, cfg in pbins.items():
    for i in range(cfg["n"]): 
        packer.add_item(Item(f"{name}_{i}", *cfg["s"]))

# packer.pack()
# packer.pack(bigger_first=False)
print("about to pack")
# print(item.position)
packer.pack(bigger_first=False, distribute_items=True, number_of_decimals=3)
print("packed")




# pozisyon=(3,4,6),3)





### PLOTLY ###
# https://plotly.com/python/3d-mesh/#mesh-cube
def vertices(xmin=0, ymin=0, zmin=0, xmax=1, ymax=1, zmax=1):
    return {
        "x": [xmin, xmin, xmax, xmax, xmin, xmin, xmax, xmax],
        "y": [ymin, ymax, ymax, ymin, ymin, ymax, ymax, ymin],
        "z": [zmin, zmin, zmin, zmin, zmax, zmax, zmax, zmax],
        "i": [7, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 6, 1, 4, 0, 3, 6],
        "j": [3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 5, 2, 0, 1, 6, 3],
        "k": [0, 7, 2, 3, 6, 7, 1, 6, 5, 5, 7, 2],
    }

# take a packer item and build parameters to a plotly mesh3d cube
def packer_to_plotly(item):
    colors = ["crimson", "limegreen", "green", "red", "cyan", "magenta", "yellow"]

    ret = vertices(
        *item.position, *[sum(x) for x in zip(item.position, item.get_dimension())]
    )
    ret["name"] = item.name
    ret["color"] = colors[ord(item.name.split("_")[0][-1]) - ord("A")]
    #print(colors[ord(item.name.split("_")[0][-1]) - ord("A")])
   # print(ret["color"])
    #print(colors[ord(item.name.split("_")[0][-1]) - ord("A")])
    return ret

# create a multi-plot figure for each bin
fig = make_subplots(rows=len(packer.bins), cols=1, specs=[[{"type":"mesh3d"}], [{"type":"mesh3d"}]])

# add a trace for each packer item
for row, pbin in enumerate(packer.bins):
    for item in pbin.items:
        fig.add_trace(go.Mesh3d(packer_to_plotly(item)), row=row+1, col=1)

# some first attempts at sorting out layout, prmarily aspect ratio
fig.update_layout(
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
    autosize=False,
    scene=dict(
        camera=dict(
            # eye=dict(x=0.1, y=0.1, z=1.5)
        ),
        aspectratio=dict(x=1, y=.2, z=0.2),
        aspectmode="manual",
        
    ),
)
# fig.write_html("file.html")

import pandas as pd

# push data into a data frame to enable more types of analysis
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            "bin_name": b.name,
            "bin_index": i,
            **packer_to_plotly(item),
            **{d: v for v, d in zip(item.get_dimension(), list("hwl"))},
            **{d + d: v for v, d in zip(item.position, list("xyz"))},
        }
        for i, b in enumerate(packer.bins)
        for item in b.items
    ]
)

# create a figure for each container (bin)
for pbin, d in df.groupby("bin_name"):
    fig = go.Figure()
    xx = []
    yy = []
    zz = []

    # create a trace for each box (bin)
    for _, r in d.iterrows():
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Mesh3d(r[["x", "y", "z", "i", "j", "k", "name", "color"]].to_dict())
        )
        xx += [r.xx, r.xx + r.h, r.xx + r.h, r.xx, r.xx, None] * 2 + [r.xx] * 5 + [None]
        yy += [r.yy, r.yy, r.yy + r.w, r.yy + r.w, r.yy, None] * 2 + [
            r.yy,
            r.yy + r.w,
            r.yy + r.w,
            r.yy,
            r.yy,
            None,
        ]
        zz += (
            [r.zz] * 5
            + [None]
            + [r.zz + r.l] * 5
            + [None]
            + [r.zz, r.zz, r.zz + r.l, r.zz + r.l, r.zz, None]
        )

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter3d(
            x=xx,
            y=yy,
            z=zz,
            mode="lines",
            line_color="black",
            line_width=2,
            hoverinfo="skip",
        )
    )
    ar = 4
    xr = max(d["x"].max()) - min(d["x"].min())
    fig.update_layout(
        title={"text": pbin, "y": 0.9, "x": 0.5, "xanchor": "center", "yanchor": "top"},
        margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
        # autosize=False,
        scene=dict(
            camera=dict(eye=dict(x=2, y=2, z=2)),
            aspectratio={
                **{"x": ar},
                **{
                    c: ((max(d[c].max()) - min(d[c].min())) / xr) * ar
                    for c in list("yz")
                },
            },
            aspectmode="manual",
        ),
    )

    fig.show()
    #try this if doesnt show.
    #fig.write_html("file.html") ```
````

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72182976/plotly-how-to-plot-cylinder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotly - how to plot Cylinder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72182976/plotly-how-to-plot-cylinder)